# HOW to fix overflow exception while connecting to ms access database from visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am new to visual basic. I am developing a project in visual basic 2010 for my mini project.I wanted to store my data inserted in visual basic form into the database created in ms access 2007.I have typed the following code but, each time i enter the values into the form and press submit I get the exception as "overflow" in a message box . I couldn't able to find out the reason for this. Please help me out.

THE FOLLOWING IS THE CODE:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class dn_register
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub dn_sub_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dn_sub.Click

        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        dataFile = "F:\MyDatabase\MyProjectDatabase.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.Close()
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "Insert into Dnr_tbl([Dname],[Age],[Bloodgroup],[Location],[Contact],[Email]) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Dname", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Age", CType(TextBox2.Text, Integer)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Bloodgroup", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Location", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Contact", CType(TextBox5.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Email", CType(TextBox6.Text, String)))

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            TextBox3.Clear()
            TextBox4.Clear()
            TextBox5.Clear()
            TextBox6.Clear()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

     End Sub

End Class
```

[And here is the snapshot of my error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhn3v.jpg)

Comment: From here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/853aec35-5b19-4126-b142-44dae2ad0a47/oledbexception-overflow?forum=vbgeneral I believe your insert query may be incorrect.

Comment: Without looking the table structure it's hard to tell if your query parameters are wrong. The most suspicious part is `cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Age", CType(TextBox2.Text, Integer)))`, since `Age` column often uses `Byte` data type.

Comment: Just as a note - it's not a good idea to store the donor's age - I would store their DOB. Ensure that your strings are the correct length.  Also, integers in VB.NET are 4 bytes, whereas they're 2 bytes in Access. You may want to use `Int16` in .NET.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First try to narrow down which parameter is causing the problem. You can either comment out all of the parameters and add them back until you find the problem (adjusting the SQL statement as needed to match the parameter count) or pick a likely suspect and comment it out and continue commenting out parameters and adjusting the SQL statement until it works. You may need to temporarily tweak the table in Access to allow nulls in the tested columns. The integer value does seem a likely candidate and I would start from there.

Once you find the problem parameter, it may be obvious that there's a datatype conflict or mismatch between VB.NET and Access or you may have to experiment a little to find which VB cast will work. The next most likely candidate in your example would be a string length problem and that would be pretty obvious from looking at the table definition and your text box input length limits.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this line is throwing the exception:

`cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Age", CType(TextBox2.Text, Integer)))`

My first suggestion is to use the appropriate control to handle numeric input such as a NumericUpDown control.

My second suggestion (if you continue to use a TextBox) is to explicitly convert the String value to an Integer using [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).

My third suggestion is to stop using CType on String values (textBox[n].Text) to convert them to Strings, it is unnecessary.

My fourth suggestion is to use [Parameter.AddWithValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) instead since it will use the data type of the value passed.

My fifth and final suggestion is to wrap your objects that implement iDisposable in Using statements or to at least explicitly dispose of them.

Here is an example of implementing suggestions 2-5, if you take my first suggestion, then #2 is unnecessary:

```
'Declare an age variable that is an Integer
Dim age As Integer

'Convert the String to an Integer
If Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, age) Then
  'Declare the connection object
  Dim con As OleDbConnection

  'Database operations should always be wrapped in Try/Catch
  Try
    'Set the connection object to a new instance
    con = New OleDbConnection(connString)

    'Create a new instance of the command object
    Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Dnr_tbl] ([Dname], [Age], [Bloodgroup], [Location], [Contact], [Email]) VALUES (@name, @age, @bloodgroup, @location, @contact, @email)", con)
      'Parameterize the query
      With cmd.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@age", age)
        .AddWithValue("@bloodgroup", TextBox3.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@location", TextBox4.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@contact", TextBox5.Text)
        .AddWithValue("@email", TextBox6.Text)
      End With

      'Open the connection
      con.Open()

      'Execute the query
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

      'Close the connection
      con.Close()

      'Clear the controls
      TextBox1.Clear() : TextBox2.Clear() : TextBox3.Clear() : TextBox4.Clear() : TextBox5.Clear() : TextBox6.Clear()
    End Using
  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
  Finally
    'Check if the connection object was initialized
    If con IsNot Nothing Then
      If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'Close the connection if it was left open(exception thrown)
        con.Close()
      End If

      'Dispose of the connection object
      con.Dispose()
    End If
  End Try
Else
  MessageBox.Show("Invalid age input.")
End If
```